# Are href attributes of a elements filtered on output to add the current path?

Tags: filters, urls

I have some code that basically looks like this (it's more complicated, but even this example shows what I'm running into):

```
echo '<a href="#">TEST</a>';
```

However, what gets sent to the browser is not `<a href="#">TEST</a>`, but instead `<a href="http://example.com/current-page#">TEST</a>`.

Is WordPress filtering this somehow to prepend the current page URL in front of the `#`?

It just occurred to me that this code is called by a shortcode, which I imagine opens up the possibility of it being filtered somehow...

Comment: Plugins/themes all disabled? Also, what browser? Does it happen in other browsers?

Comment: All browsers, haven't disabled plugins yet, though. It did just occur to me that it's being called by a shortcode, so I suppose that may be a problem.

Comment: Are you sure it's what is really happening (link changed in page source) rather than what is browser displaying to you? As per answer it is expected of browser to interpret such link as link to current page with anchor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ran that exact code snippet on WP 3.3 to test.  In practice, `<a href="#">test</a>` is rendered in the markup correctly, but the browser will attempt to navigate to `http://example.com/current-page/#` when you hover over the link or click on it.

This is the expected behavior of a link like this ... so unless you have other code on the page that's actively changing the links, this is what I'd expect to see.

Tested under both Chrome and IE just to make sure I wasn't crazy.